# DAX Custom Number Format

Tags: excel, format, powerbi, dax

I'm stumped on a seemingly simple format issue for Power BI.
I'm trying to format the remainder of a number into a custom fraction (13ths)

For example: 755.38 should show as 755 **5/13**

[image: Excel Format]

In Excel, I use the custom fraction formula "# #/13"

In DAX I'm using the `FORMAT` function with the format as "#. #/13".

[image: DAXFormat]

This just takes the remainder and displays it with a "/13" on the end.  it does not divide the remainder correctly.

Example 755.38 is showing as 755. **4/13** when the correct calculation is 755 5/13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know that you can do it with just `FORMAT`, but you can definitely put the pieces together yourself. For example,

```
Measure = 
VAR Num = SUM(Table1[Number])
VAR Frac = ROUND(13*(Num - INT(Num)), 0)
RETURN FORMAT(INT(Num), "0 ") & Frac & "/13"
```

[image: Samle Output]

Answer (score 1):

Excel and DAX formatting strings are not identical. The documentation for Excel custom formats has examples for fractions, but the DAX documentation for the FORMAT function has no reference to fractions, so it appears that fractions as they are displayed in Excel are not possible with DAX.

[Excel documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/review-guidelines-for-customizing-a-number-format-c0a1d1fa-d3f4-4018-96b7-9c9354dd99f5)

[DAX FORMAT documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/custom-numeric-formats-for-the-format-function)

Comment: thanks for the response.  Are you aware of anyway i can accomplish this custom fraction in Power BI? (DAX or another way)

Comment: Not with formatting. You'd need to stitch together a text string.